# Unable to run botium for watson connector

Tags: chatbot

I am trying to test Watson assistance Chatbot

```
{   "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "IBM Watson",
       "SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_MODE": "all",

      "SCRIPTING_FORMAT": "xlsx",
      "SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTROW": 2,
      "SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTCOL": 1,

      "CONTAINERMODE": "watson",
      "WATSON_APIKEY": "*********************************",
      "WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID": "*********************"
    }   } }
```

but it is failing with following exception

```
 Cannot build watson container: 'Watson workspace connection failed: { Error: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.\n    at Request._callback
```

I have provided correct credential

> Skill Details Skill Name:My first skill
>
> Skill ID:****************************
>
> **Workspace ID:*****************************

and

API Key

> Service Credentials Service Credentials Name:Service credentials-1
>
> **Api Key:********************

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have to adapt the [Watson Service Endpoint Url](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#service-endpoint) using the [WATSON_URL capability](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-watson#watson_url)

And you should switch to the V2 Version of the Assistant API - https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-watson#watson_assistant_version - using the Watson assistant ID instead of the workspace id: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-watson#watson_assistant_id-

```
"WATSON_ASSISTANT_VERSION": "V2",
"WATSON_URL": "your service endpoint",
"WATSON_APIKEY": "....",
"WATSON_ASSISTANT_ID": "....",
```